# Centering on a canvas object within an HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have an Html5 canvas which i am drawing squares to.
The canvas itself is roughly the size of the window.
When i detect a click on a square i would like to translate the canvas so that the square is roughly in the center of the window. Any insights, hints, or straight-forward replies are welcome.

Here is what i tried so far:

If a square is at point (1000, 1000) I would simply translate the canvas (-1000, -1000). I know i need to add an offset so that it is centered in the window. However, the canvas always ends up off of the visible window (too far in the upper-left corner somewhere).

A more complex scenario:

Ultimately i would like to be able to center on a clicked object on a canvas that is transformed (rotated & skewed). I'm going for an isometric effect which seems to work really well. **I'm wondering if this transformation affects the centering logic/math at all?**

Comment: Do you really want to translate the canvas, or do you just want to move the content on the canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Transforming from screen to world and back

When working with non standard axis (or projections) such as isometrix it is always best to use a transformation matrix. It will cover every possible 2D projection with the same simple functions.

The coordinates of the iso world are called world coordinates. All you objects are stored as world coordinates. When you render them you project those coordinates to the screen coordinates using a transformation matrix.

#### The matrix, not a movie.

The matrix represents the direction and size in screen coordinates of the world 
 x and y axis and the screen location of the  world  origin  (0,0)

For iso that is

- x axis across 1 down 0.5
- y axis across -1 down 0.5
- z axis up 1 (-1 as up is the reverse of down) but this example does not use z

So the matrix as an array

```
const isoMat = [1,0.5,-1,0.5,0,0];  // ISO (pixel art) dimorphic projection
```

The first two are the x axis, the next two the y axis and the last two values are the screen coordinates of the origin.

#### Use the matrix to transform points

You apply a matrix to a point, this transforms the point from one coordinate system to another. You can also convert back via a inverse transform.

#### World to screen

You will need to convert from world coordinates to screen coordinates.

```
function worldToScreen(pos,retPos){
    retPos.x = pos.x * isoMat[0] + pos.y * isoMat[2] + isoMat[4];
    retPos.y = pos.x * isoMat[1] + pos.y * isoMat[3] + isoMat[5];  
}
```

In the demo I ignore the origin as I set that at the center of the canvas at all times. Thus remove the origin from that function

```
function worldToScreen(pos,retPos){
    retPos.x = pos.x * isoMat[0] + pos.y * isoMat[2];
    retPos.y = pos.x * isoMat[1] + pos.y * isoMat[3];  
}
```

#### Screen to world.

You will also need to convert from the screen coordinates to the world. For this you need to use the inverse transform. It's a bit like the inverse of multiply  `a * 2 = b` is the inverse of `b / 2 = a`

There is a standard method for calculating the inverse matrix as follows

```
const invMatrix = [];  // inverse matrix
// I call the next line cross, most call it the determinant which I 
// think is stupid as it is effectively a cross product and is used
// like you would use a cross product. Anyways I digress
const cross = isoMat[0] * isoMat[3] - isoMat[1] * isoMat[2];
invMatrix[0] =  isoMat[3] / cross;
invMatrix[1] = -isoMat[1] / cross;
invMatrix[2] = -isoMat[2] / cross;
invMatrix[3] =  isoMat[0] / cross;
```

Then we have a function that converts from the screen x,y to the world position

```
function screenToWorld(pos,retPos){
    const x = pos.x - isoMat[4];
    const y = pos.y - isoMat[5];
    retPos.x = x * invMatrix[0] + y * invMatrix[2];
    retPos.y = x * invMatrix[1] + y * invMatrix[3];  
}
```

So you get the mouse coords as screen pixels, use the above function to convert to world coords. Then you can use the world coords to find the object you are looking for.

To move a world object to the screen center you convert its coords to screen coords, add the position on the screen (the canvas center) and set the transform matrix origin to that location.

#### The demo

The demo creates a set of boxes in world coordinates. It sets the 2D context transform to the `isoMat` (isometric projection) via `ctx.setTransform(`

Every frame I convert the mouse screen coords to world coords then use that to check which box the mouse is over.

If the mouse button is down I then convert that box from world coords to screen and add the screen center. To smooth the step the new screen center is chased (smoothed)..

Well you should be able to work it out in the code, any problems ask in the comments.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const moveSpeed = 0.4;
const boxMin = 20;
const boxMax = 50;
const boxCount = 100;
const boxArea = 2000;
// some canvas vals
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var cw = w / 2;  // center 
var ch = h / 2;
var globalTime;




const U = undefined;
// Helper function 
const doFor = (count, cb) => { var i = 0; while (i < count && cb(i++) !== true); };
const eachOf = (array, cb) => { var i = 0; const len = array.length; while (i < len && cb(array[i], i++, len) !== true ); };
const setOf = (count, cb) => {var a = [],i = 0; while (i < count) { a.push(cb(i ++)) } return a };
const randI = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => (Math.random() * (max - min) + min) | 0;
const rand = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
// mouse function and object
const mouse  = {x : 0, y : 0, button : false, world : {x : 0, y : 0}}
function mouseEvents(e){
 mouse.x = e.pageX;
 mouse.y = e.pageY;
 mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
}
["down","up","move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse"+name,mouseEvents));


// boxes in world coordinates.
const boxes = [];
function draw(){
   if(this.dead){
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"; 
      ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
   }
   ctx.strokeStyle = this.col;
   ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
   ctx.strokeRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);

   // the rest is just overkill
   if(this.col === "red"){
      this.mr = 10;
   }else{
      this.mr = 1;
   }
   this.mc += (this.mr-this.m) * 0.45;
   this.mc *= 0.05;
   this.m += this.mc;
   for(var i = 0; i < this.m; i ++){
      const m = this.m * (i + 1);
      ctx.globalAlpha = 1-(m / 100);
      ctx.strokeRect(this.x-m,this.y-m,this.w,this.h);
   }
}


// make random boxes.
function createBoxes(){
  boxes.length = 0;
  boxes.push(...setOf(boxCount,()=>{
      return {
        x : randI(cw- boxArea/ 2, cw + boxArea/2), 
        y : randI(ch- boxArea/ 2, ch + boxArea/2), 
        w : randI(boxMin,boxMax), 
        h : randI(boxMin,boxMax),
        m : 5,
        mc : 0,
        mr : 5,
        col : "black",
        dead : false,
        draw : draw,
        isOver : isOver,
     }
   }));
} 
// use mouse world coordinates to find box under mouse
function isOver(x,y){
   return x > this.x && x < this.x + this.w && y > this.y && y < this.y + this.h;
}
var overBox;
function findBox(x,y){
   if(overBox){
       overBox.col = "black";
   }
   overBox = undefined;
   eachOf(boxes,box=>{
     if(box.isOver(x,y)){
        overBox = box;
        box.col = "red";
        return true;
     }
   })
}
function drawBoxes(){
   boxes.forEach(box=>box.draw());
}
// next 3 values control the movement of the origin
// rather than move instantly the currentPos chases the new pos.        
const currentPos = {x :0, y : 0};
const newPos = {x :0, y : 0};
const chasePos = {x :0, y : 0};
// this function does the chasing
function updatePos(){
  chasePos.x += (newPos.x - currentPos.x) * moveSpeed;
  chasePos.y += (newPos.y - currentPos.y) * moveSpeed;
  chasePos.x *= moveSpeed;
  chasePos.y *= moveSpeed;
  currentPos.x += chasePos.x;
  currentPos.y += chasePos.y;
}

// ISO matrix and inverse matrix plus 2world and 2 screen
const isoMat = [1,0.5,-1,0.5,0,0];
const invMatrix = [];
const cross = isoMat[0] * isoMat[3] - isoMat[1] * isoMat[2];
invMatrix[0] =  isoMat[3] / cross;
invMatrix[1] = -isoMat[1] / cross;
invMatrix[2] = -isoMat[2] / cross;
invMatrix[3] =  isoMat[0] / cross;

function screenToWorld(pos,retPos){
    const x = pos.x - isoMat[4];
    const y = pos.y - isoMat[5];
    retPos.x = x * invMatrix[0] + y * invMatrix[2];
    retPos.y = x * invMatrix[1] + y * invMatrix[3];  
}
function worldToScreen(pos,retPos){
    retPos.x = pos.x * isoMat[0] + pos.y * isoMat[2];// + isoMat[4];
    retPos.y = pos.x * isoMat[1] + pos.y * isoMat[3];// + isoMat[5];  
}

// main update function
function update(timer){
    // standard frame setup
    globalTime = timer;
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;           // reset alpha
    if(w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight){
      cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
      ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
      createBoxes();
    }else{
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.font = "28px arial";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText("Click on a box to center it.",cw,28);
    
    // update position      
    updatePos();
    isoMat[4] = currentPos.x;
    isoMat[5] = currentPos.y;
    // set the screen transform to the iso matrix
    // all drawing can now be done in world coordinates.
    ctx.setTransform(isoMat[0], isoMat[1], isoMat[2], isoMat[3], isoMat[4], isoMat[5]);
    // convert the mouse to world coordinates
    screenToWorld(mouse,mouse.world);
    // find box under mouse
 findBox(mouse.world.x, mouse.world.y);
    // if mouse down and over a box
    if(mouse.button && overBox){
       mouse.button = false;
       overBox.dead = true;  // make it gray
       // get the screen coordinates of the box
       worldToScreen({
            x:-(overBox.x + overBox.w/2),
            y:-(overBox.y + overBox.h/2),
          },newPos
       );
       // move it to the screen center
       newPos.x += cw;
       newPos.y += ch;

    }
    // forget what the following function does, think it does something like draw boxes, but I am guessing.. :P
 drawBoxes();
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
canvas { position : absolute; top : 0px; left : 0px; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```